# Why do I see "Waiting for Debugger" on my Android?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

(I know I've asked this before):

Now, for some reason, I can select my phone from the list of debugging apps. And when I start debugging (Visual Studio; C#; Xamarin) the app rebuilds and then seems to copy it to the attached (via USB) phone. But then all I see is "Waiting for Debugger: Waiting for the debugger to attach" and nothing happens after that. "Enabled developer instrumentation and debugging" is selected.

Comment: Sometimes attaching with an debugger can fail if there are other Android tools also using the adb/debugging interface. E.g. an opened Android Studio or even an IntelliJ with Android plugin can prevent debugger access. Therefore I would recommend to close unneeded applications that may contain Android debugging functionality.

Comment: Not on my machine. Window 10 + Visual Studio + Android. No Android Studio.

Comment: What else can I do? What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

Under Developer Options, one of the options is "Wait for Debugger". Why I didn't see it before, only my therapist knows.